# SSRS Line Chart--One line defined by a parameter (a subset), one line an overall average (parameter independent)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, linegraph

I am new to SSRS 2008R2 reports, so this may or may not be easy, although it should be very basic.  Here is a table of what my data looks like in the query designer:

[image]

You can see that Provider.ProviderName (the Pro... column in the picture) is a parameter as well as the beginning and ending months.  It is straightforward to add a line to a line chart depicting the No Show Value for the provider selected in the drop-down menu for the report (each month is one data point, typically for 12 months).  But I cannot figure out how to add a line that shows the monthly average No Show Value across all providers, for the same selected time period, no matter what Provider is selected.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the Provider parameter definition in SSRS but unlink it from this dataset, so that it returns the results for all Providers.

Then in the existing Values entry (representing the Selected Provider), I would add an Iif function to return Nothing unless the Dataset Provider Field matches the Parameter provider.

Then I would add a new Values entry (series) for the Average No Show Value which will aggregate across all Providers.

Comment: OK.  I tried =iif(Fields!Provider_Name=Parameters!ProviderProviderName.Value,Sum(Fields!No_Show_Value),0) in the value field of the series properties, and it gives an error.  (I know the 0 should be null but I couldn't code that either).

Comment: The error says:  The Y expression for the chart contains an error:  Operator '=' is not defined for types 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field' and 'Object'.  I did get the average line to show up on the graph, though.

Comment: Try this: `=Sum(iif(Fields!Provider_Name.Value = Parameters!ProviderProviderName.Value , Fields!No_Sh‌ow_Value,  CDec(0))`

Comment: Mike, thanks so much for your help.  I was able to use the above formulation to display both the overall average and the provider specific no show values in a table, so I know it is working.  But for some reason it is only displaying the average no show value line on the line graph.  No matter what provider name I try, it doesn't show up on the graph, although it calculates it correctly in the table.

Comment: Maybe this is useful:  if a provider had no no shows (the provider was inactive), then a line of zeros for the provider shows up on the graph.

Comment: This area gets tricky when your Datasets are SSAS/MDX. `Parameters!ProviderProviderName.Value` will return an MDX reference to the chosen dimension member. I would try `Trim ( Parameters!ProviderProviderName.Label )` instead.

Comment: Trim() did not make a difference in this case.  However, when I added CDec it worked!  The final expression for Y was this:  =Sum(iif(Fields!Provider_Name.Value = Parameters!ProviderProviderName.Label,
 CDec(Fields!ID__No_Show.Value), CDec(0))).  I guess maybe the table was displaying it as a string?  Anyway, this works and I get both lines on the graph.  Compared to R, this is incredibly difficult and quite convoluted.  Thank you so much for your help--I never would have figured that out.

Comment: Yeah I've really gone off the SSRS integration with SSAS and I avoid it wherever possible.